# Trying to access the store in a main page and I'm getting the error

Tags: vuex, vuejs3

Main.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
      <div class="home_page_header">
        <h1>My Recipe</h1>
        <button @click="toggleOpen">Add New Recipe</button>
      </div>
  
      <div v-for="recipe in $store.state.recipes" :key="recipe.Recipe_Name">
        <h1 >{{recipe.Recipe_Name}}</h1>
        <p>{{recipe.Ingredients}}</p>
        <router-link :to="`/recipe/${recipe.Recipe_Name}`">
          <button>View Recipe</button>
        </router-link>
        <router-view/>
      </div>
  
    <div>
      <h1></h1>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  
      <div class="popUp" v-show="openUp">
      <div>
        <label for="receipe_name">Recipe Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="receipe_name" v-model="values.receipeName"/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="ingredients_name">Ingredients</label>
        
        <input type="text" id="ingredients_name" v-model="values.ingredientsName" v-for="i in values.ingredientsRows" :key="i"/>
        <button @click="addrows" >Add Ingredients</button>
      </div>
      <div><button @click="onSubmit">Submit</button></div>
      <div><button @click="toggleClose">Close</button></div>
    </div>
  
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
    import store from '@/store/index.js'
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        values:{
          receipeName:'',
          ingredientsName:'',
          ingredientsRows:1
        },
        values_final:{
          receipeName:'',
          ingredientsName:'',
          ingredientsRows:1
        },
        openUp : false
       
      }
    },
  
    
    methods: {
  
      toggleOpen(){
        this.openUp = true
      },
      toggleClose(){
        this.openUp = false
      },
      onSubmit(){
        if(this.values.receipeName || this.values.ingredientsName == ''){
          alert('enter the full details')
        }
      },
      addrows(){
        this.values.ingredientsRows++;
      },

      
     
      },
      computed: this.$store.commit('Add_Recipes',{...values_final})
    }
  
  
  </script>
```

store:

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({

  state: {
    recipes:[
      {
        Recipe_Name: 'curd',
        Ingredients:'xxxxxx'
      }
    ]
  },


  mutations: {
    Add_Recipes (state,recipe) {
      state.recipes.push(recipe)
    }
  },
```

> Error : app.js:340 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$store')...

I'm trying to create a recipe app by using option API, I have one main page. In that main page that contains one title and add recipe button to add the details. And another one is a popup to enter the recipe details. so here after entering all the details that should show in a main page. I'm trying to access the store in a main page but iam getting the above error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to move the import statement of your store to your `main.js` file (not your Main.vue). And add `app.use(store)` after you created the app there with `const app = createApp(…)`.

Comment: its already there, but I didn't added that file content here

Comment: Could you please add your `main.js` to your question?